How can I combine these two formulas?
I have the following formula which gives me a "Status" of a location if the condition is met.
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J2),ISBLANK(L2)),"Active",IF(ISBLANK(L2),"Dormant","Deleted"))

I want to combine it with.
=IF(OR(K2="",K2>=TODAY()),"Dormant","Active")

However, I also want K2 to add 90 days to a date in J2, if one is present so that the expiration date re-activates the location automatically when the date has passed.


You have four "things" (states) being True or False, that you are acting on...
ISBLANK(J2), ISBLANK(K2), ISBLANK(L2), K2>=TODAY()
2 to the power of 4 is 16, so create a table with sixteen rows.
Fill in the rows with the numbers 0 to 15 in binary; thus you get all the possible combinations for the four "things".
With that present - ponder on each combination and see if it is "valid" - i.e. is meaningful - and what the outcome should be there
=> Active, Dormant or Deleted
In that pondering you might find that one or more of the "things" doesn't matter; change that 1 (True) to X for "Doesn't matter"(i.e. doesn't need to be checked for).
Base on your filled in table, decide how the formula should look.
For the initiated; you should be able to determine a minimal formula by using a Karnaugh diagram - sadly it was so long ago I used those that I cannot tell how to use it here.
0 to 15, written in binary:

0000
0001  
0010  
0011  
0100  
0101  
0110  
0111  
1000
1001  
1010  
1011  
1100  
1101  
1110  
1111  

